# Select dentro de Select en consulta SQL con VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

Tengo 2 tablas:

> -Articulo
>
> -Articulo_Panio

La tabla **Articulo** tiene, entre otros, el campo **Stock_Local** (que seria el stock que se encuentra fisicamente en el negocio) y en la tabla **Articulo_Panio** se encuentran los articulos que estan dentro de cada paño (que tiene cada vendedor).

Necesito agregar un campo a la tabla Articulo llamado "**Stock_General**" (el Stock local + la suma de cada incurrencia que encuentre en Articulo_Paño del articulo en si).

Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera,

```
    TablaArticulo.Columns.Add("Stock_General", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    For Each row As DataRow In TablaArticulo.Rows
        row("Stock_General") = CInt(buscarStockGeneral(row("IdArticulo")) + row("Stock_Local"))
    Next
```

> y funciona .Pero es un proceso muy lento (al punto que me cuelga el debbugger (son 10.000 registros). Estoy seguro que haciendo un SELECT
>   dentro de otro se acortaría mucho el tiempo de carga, pero no se como..

Asi esta la función completa:

```
Public Sub LlenaTablaArticulo()
    Try
        conectarse()
        //Consulta SQL de la tabla Articulos con un INNER JOIN a Departamento
        Dim strSql As String = "Select IdArticulo, Codigo, Descripcion, Costo, Ganancia, PrecioFinal, Articulo.IdDepartamento, Departamento.Nombre as departamento, Proveedor, Stock_Local from Articulo inner join Departamento on Articulo.IdDepartamento=Departamento.IdDepartamento"
        Dim adaptador As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, conexion)
        TablaArticulo = New DataTable
        adaptador.Fill(TablaArticulo)

        //Una vez llenada la TablaArticulo, le agrego el campo Stock_General y por cada fila verifico con la funcion BuscarStockGeneral si hay de ese articulo en los paños
        TablaArticulo.Columns.Add("Stock_General", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        For Each row As DataRow In TablaArticulo.Rows
            row("Stock_General") = CInt(buscarStockGeneral(row("IdArticulo")) + row("Stock_Local"))
        Next

        conexion.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Esta es la funcion BuscarStockGeneral

```
Function buscarStockGeneral(ByRef IdArticulo As String)
    Dim contador As Integer

    Try
        contador = CType(TablaArticulo_Panio.Compute("SUM(Cantidad)", "IdArticulo=" & IdArticulo), String)
    Catch ex As Exception
        contador = 0
    End Try

    Return contador

End Function
```

---

**EDIT (SOLUCION FINAL)**

Asi quedo la consulta utilizando un **SELECT** dentro de otro que sume los campos encontrados con **SUM()**, y utilizando la funcion **IIF(ISNULL(),0,SUM())** para evitar los campos nulos.

```
"Select IdArticulo, Codigo, Descripcion, Costo, Ganancia, PrecioFinal, Articulo.IdDepartamento, Departamento.Nombre as departamento, Proveedor, Stock_Local, (Stock_Local + (SELECT IIf(IsNull(sum(Cantidad)),0,sum(Cantidad)) FROM Articulo_Panio WHERE IdArticulo = Articulo.IdArticulo)) as Stock_General from Articulo inner join Departamento on Articulo.IdDepartamento=Departamento.IdDepartamento"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba la siguiente consulta con ella deberias obtener el total de la suma de la tabla TablaArticulo_Panio

```
Select IdArticulo, Codigo, Descripcion, Costo, Ganancia, PrecioFinal, 
Articulo.IdDepartamento, Departamento.Nombre as departamento, Proveedor,Stock_Local, 
(select sum(Cantidad) TablaArticulo_Panio where IdArticulo = a.idArticulo ) as totalArticuloPanio
from Articulo a  inner join Departamento d on a.IdDepartamento = d.IdDepartamento
```

Comment: No me anda. Estoy tratando de depurarlo. Cuando pones "FROM Articulo a.." estas haciendo un alias a la tabla Articulo? Luego cuando pones a.IdArticulo sería lo mismo que poner Articulo.IdArticulo. Es asi?

Comment: asi es, solo es un alias en sql server asi me ha funcionado

Comment: Ahh ahi esta! esta cargando bien la tabla, me da error el DataGridview porque cuando no hay articulo en los paños no devuelve 0 la funcion SUM sino que el campo queda en blanco y genera error ante un DBNull.

Comment: no entendi esta ultima parte que te regresa la consulta cuando no hay articulo?

Comment: No devuelve nada, el campo totalArticulosPanio queda vacío o Nulo. Y ahí me genera el error

Comment: eso lo puedes resolver con isnull(sum(Cantidad),0) en sqlserver o validando desde codigo que cuando sea null asigne 0